# error setting anaconda python 3.7 interpreter on pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, python-3.7

I'm having trouble to set anaconda python 3.7 on pycharm , and i get this error:

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch/repodata.json.bz2

---

from the excuted command :

C:\Users\Matan\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe create -p C:\Users\Matan\Anaconda3\envs\untitled2 -y python=3.7

---

Command output:

Collecting package metadata: ...working... failed

WARNING: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch/repodata.json.bz2
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

SSLError(MaxRetryError('HTTPSConnectionPool(host=\'repo.anaconda.com\', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/r/noarch/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by SSLError("Can\'t connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))'))

Comment: What happens when you try to install anything from your conda prompt? If this also times out, then it is a proxy error. Is this your office network that your PC is connected to?

Comment: Which PyCharm version do you use? Try [2019.1.3 RC](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=23004355).

Comment: i didnt try to install from the conda promot beacuse i dont know how and it my home network.

Comment: im using pycharm 2019.1.2